# Moving into earlier cell of DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am writing an application using DataGridView in VB.Net

On DataGridView, Cell(column(0),row(0)) is used for searching into database the item code. What I want is when the item code is not found in database, the cursor should be back on Cell(column(0),row(0)), which is the cell I used for searching the item code.

Below are the code I have :

```
 Private Sub DGV1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellEndEdit
    Dim flag_cell_edited As Boolean
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    Dim CurrentColumn As Integer
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        flag_cell_edited = True
        CurrentRow = e.RowIndex
        CurrentColumn = e.ColumnIndex
        Call Koneksi()
        CMD = New OleDbCommand("Select Nama_Matakuliah, SKS from tbmatakuliah where Kode_MK = '" & DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & "' and Program_Studi = '" & txt_ps.Text & "'", CONN)
        DR = CMD.ExecuteReader
        DR.Read()
        If DR.HasRows Then
            DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = DR.Item("Nama_Matakuliah")
            DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = DR.Item("SKS")
            DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).ReadOnly = True
            DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
            DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Selected = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Kode Mata Kuliah " & DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & " Tidak ditemukan", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pengisian Kartu Hasil Studi")
            DGV1.CurrentCell = DGV1(CurrentColumn, CurrentRow)
            flag_cell_edited = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Really need Help.. Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
Private Sub DGV1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellEndEdit
'
Dim flag_cell_edited As Boolean
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
Dim CurrentColumn As Integer
'
  LastColumn = e.ColumnIndex
  LastRow = e.RowIndex
  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    flag_cell_edited = True
    CurrentRow = e.RowIndex
    CurrentColumn = e.ColumnIndex
    Call Koneksi()
    CMD = New OleDbCommand("Select Nama_Matakuliah, SKS from tbmatakuliah where Kode_MK = '" & DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & "' and Program_Studi = '" & txt_ps.Text & "'", CONN)
    DR = CMD.ExecuteReader
    DR.Read()
    If DR.HasRows Then
        DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = DR.Item("Nama_Matakuliah")
        DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = DR.Item("SKS")
        DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).ReadOnly = True
        DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
        DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Selected = True
    Else
        MsgBox("Kode Mata Kuliah " & DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & " Tidak ditemukan", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pengisian Kartu Hasil Studi")
        DGV1.CurrentCell = DGV1(CurrentColumn, CurrentRow)
        flag_cell_edited = False
        DGV1.CurrentCell = DGV1(LastColumn, LastRow)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give a shot and I'll let you know

Comment: I have tried your answer Zaf Khan, but it still not working... I am thinking to do on other way.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I had made a typo in the code above, the line `DGV1.CurrentCell = (LastColumn, LastRow)` should have been written as `DGV1.CurrentCell = DGV1(LastColumn, LastRow)`